# Is there a way to constrain a type to be new'ed object only in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following definition:

```js
declare class Foo {
    name: string

    constructor(name: string)
}
declare function setFoo(foo: Foo): void

setFoo(new Foo("Ace"))   // Good
setFoo({ name: "Ace" })  // Also Good
```

Is it possible in Typescript to constrain the Foo type in setFoo() to be a new'ed object only? In other words, can we somehow explicitly disallow object literals? So what I want is:

```js
setFoo(new Foo("Ace"))   // Good
setFoo({ name: "Ace" })  // Compiler Error
```

My current understanding is that this is not possible, but would love to be proven wrong.

The reason I'm wanting this is because I'm working on a public TS library and some constructors will have subtle side-effects than their object literal counterparts. For methods that use these objects, using the object literals will actually lead to future errors. Users will not need to be aware of the side-effects if I can just disallow the object literals to be used (on a compiler level). Otherwise, I can only rely on runtime checks.

Comment: If you want two types to be incompatible they need to be [structurally incompatible](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-prevent-two-types-from-being-structurally-compatible); can you add a [private property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#private-and-protected-members-in-classes) to your classes like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJR5ZW)?  If so that will essentially make it impossible for something else to be passed in (without type assertions, that is).  If you can't, then please elaborate on your requirements.

Comment: @jcalz That's actually quite perfect for my scenario. Though somewhat hacky, the private field can even be appropriately named to hint the user when they do use an object literal and encounter the error. Tyvm, would you mind making an answer for this?

Comment: I would be happy to do so when I get a chance, although right now it is bedtime in my time zone.

Comment:  TIL such field is called a 'brand' member in typescript. Very cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript's type system is mostly [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#structural-typing), meaning that two types `A` and `B` are considered equivalent/compatible if they have equivalent/compatible *structures*.  Two object types with the same property key and value types are the same type.  So in `interface A {x: string}` and `interface B {x: string}`, the types `A` and `B` are interchangeable.  It doesn't matter that the names `A` and `B` are different, or that they were declared in different places.

This is different from a [nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system) type system (like Java's) where two types are only equivalent/compatible if they have equivalent/compatible *declarations*.  In a nominal type system, interfaces `A` and `B` above would be incompatible and you couldn't assign one to the other.

---

In a structural type system, your `Foo` class instance type is structurally identical to `{name: string}` and so the two types are interchangeable.  Often this is what people want in JavaScript (well, for non-`class` types, anyway). But sometimes there is a desire for more nominal-ish typing where `Foo` could be considered distinct from `{name: string}`.  There are no official nominal types in TypeScript, but there are a few features which yield similar results.

For `class` instance types specifically, you can introduce [a `private` or `protected` property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#private-and-protected-members-in-classes).  TypeScript treats such properties as nominal, and only considers class instance types compatible if their private/protected properties come from the same declaration.  So if you have `class A {private x: string}` and `class B {private x: string}`, the compiler will not see `A` and `B` as identical.  So you can use this to make `Foo` different from `{name: string}`:

```
declare class Foo {
    name: string
    private definitelyFoo: true;
    constructor(name: string)
}
declare function setFoo(foo: Foo): void
    
setFoo(new Foo("Ace"))   // Good
setFoo({ name: "Ace" })  // Compiler Error
setFoo({ name: "Ace", definitelyFoo: true })  // Compiler Error
```

The `definitelyFoo` property is private to `Foo`, and causes it to be distinct from `{name: string}`, and also distinct from `{name: string, definitelyFoo: true}`.  It is still possible with [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) and the like to force the compiler to accept something which did not come from the `Foo` class declaration:

```
setFoo({ name: "Ace", definitelyFoo: true } as { name: string } as Foo)  // okay again
```

but you wouldn't really be able to do this *accidentally*.

---

Note that if you were asking about an `interface` instead of a `class`, you wouldn't be able to add `private` or a `protected` member.  (The same goes if you were asking about primitive types like `string` or `number`.)  In these cases you can still sort of simulate nominal types by giving your types [a "brand" property](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-prevent-two-types-from-being-structurally-compatible) which is unlikely to show up accidentally.  That is, you make the structure different, so that your formerly identical structures are now not identical:

```
namespace Foos {
    const privateProperty = Symbol("privateProperty");
    export interface Foo {
        name: string
        [privateProperty]: true;
    }

    export function getFoo(name: string): Foo {
        return { name, [privateProperty]: true };
    }
    export declare function setFoo(foo: Foo): void;

}

Foos.setFoo(Foos.getFoo("Ace"))   // Good
Foos.setFoo({ name: "Ace" })  // Compiler Error
const notSame = Symbol("privateProperty");
Foos.setFoo({ name: "Ace", [notSame]: true }); // Compiler Error


setFoo({ name: "Ace", definitelyFoo: true } as { name: string } as Foos.Foo)  // okay again
```

Here we've branded `Foo` with a `symbol`-keyed property which isn't exported from the module, so it's not easy for anyone outside to get a compatible value.  (Unique symbols are nominal-ish in TypeScript also.)

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-SQkpl8sVys9gp92s0uu8O-jPcHWXItgHvR9IErcERiMNcJimM9nkvN5aQ+RcgKTEDDmOU5zlBaCfCRAskzccREShOckmPNFMWxEBcXxWkfCAA)